# setX() and setY() conflict with align rule in relative layout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

now I am implement a hard code of a custom relative layout, the problem is, when I use parameter of relative layout, it works well. But once I add setX and setY method, they conflict. What I actually want in my code is to dynamically set the view one by one according to the first view's position.

Here when I set the X to 50,  get 50 width disappeared in the right side where the mMapView2 keep his original place.

To solve this problem the only method I could do now is to make my code tedious, cos i have many views inside relative layout here.

```
    MapView mMapView1 = new MapView(getActivity());
    mMapView1.setX(50);
    mMapView1.setId(1);
    LayoutParams mLayoutParams1 = new LayoutParams(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/3);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(mMapView1, mLayoutParams1);

    MapView mMapView2 = new MapView(getActivity());
    mMapView2.setId(2);
    LayoutParams mLayoutParams2 = new LayoutParams(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/3);
    mLayoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,1);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(mMapView2, mLayoutParams2);
```